# How to filter data by channel in config file of sync gate way in Couchbase?

Tags: laravel, couchbase, couchbase-sync-gateway

I connected to sync gate way via Api ,but I don't know how to filter some data and use them in my laravel project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not filtering by channel in the syncgateway config, the filtering is the outcome of the sync-function, but it is more of a passive result of attaching a channel to a document.
I have no idea which version you are using because your question lacks it, however configuration is pretty straight forward.

you basically have 2 options of attaching a channel to a document, the second is overriding the first:
1. don't have any sync function in the config file and just rely on a "channels" property, that property will make the document sync to the appropriate channels.
for example:

```
{ "name": "Duke", "lastName": "Nukem", "channels": ["DukeNukem","Duke"] }
```

2. Have a sync function in the config file:
For the document:
     { "name": "Duke", "lastName": "Nukem" }

you might have that sync function that will do the same:

```
function(doc, oldDoc){
   if (doc.name && doc.lastName) {
        channel(doc.name);
        channel(doc.name + doc.lastName);
    }
}
```

please note that you will have to grant permission to the user to able to see a channel.

in the client side you would need that user with the permission, and if you are not filtering for a channel  - you will get the docs whenever you sync.

please read more [here](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/guides/sync-gateway/channels/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Swift example on the client side on how to use the "channels" to route data:

```
let manager = CBLManager()
let database = try! manager.databaseNamed(dbName)
let pull = self.database.createPullReplication(url)
// We need to sync channels 
pull.channels = ["somechannels"]
pull.start()
```

A concrete example on a `Store` management application, every documents belong to a Store would be saved with channels contain the `storeID`.
On the client side, when syncing we will put the `storeID` inside `channels` so that the sync will get only the documents belong to that `Store`. (we are using the default sync function)

Note that, there are security concern that you need to take into consideration, read more [here](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/guides/sync-gateway/authentication.html).